# Node.js timeout with requestify POST

Tags: node.js, post, requestify

Im trying to request a status of a user, with a POST from node.js to a PHP file.
My issue is that the webservice Im calling is VERY slow to reply(4 sec), so I think the .then finishes before the 4 sec, and therefore returns nothing. Got any idea if i can extend the time for the request?

```
requestify.post('https://example.com/', {
              email: 'foo@bar.com'
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                var answer = response.getBody();
                console.log("answer:" + answer);
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not that knowledgeable on requestify but are you sure you can use post to a https address? In the readme only requestify.request(...) uses a https address as an example. ([see readme](https://github.com/ranm8/requestify))

One tip I can definitely give you though is to always catch your promise:

```html
requestify.get(URL).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.getBody())
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('Requestify Error', err);
    next(err);
});
```

This should at least give you the error of your promise and you can specify your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Each call to Requestify allows you to pass through an `Options` object, the definition of that object is described here: [Requestify API Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requestify#api-reference)

You are using the `short` method for POST, so I'll show that first, but this same syntax will work for `put` as well, notice that `get`, `delete`, `head` do not accept a data argument, you send url query parameters through the `params` config property.

```
requestify.post(url, data, config)
requestify.put(url, data, config)
requestify.get(url, config)
requestify.delete(url, config)
requestify.head(url, config)
```

Now, `config` has a `timeout` property

> **timeout** {number}
>
> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request.

So we can specify the a timeout of 60 seconds with this syntax:

```
var config = {};
config.timeout = 60000;
requestify.post(url, data, config)
```

or inline:

```
requestify.post(url, data, { timeout: 60000 })
```

So lets put that together now into your original request:

> as @Jabalaja pointed out, you should catch any exception messages, however you should do this with the error argument on the continuation. 
>   (`.then`)

```
requestify.post('https://example.com/', {
    email: 'foo@bar.com'
}, {
    timeout: 60000
})
.then(function(response) {
    var answer = response.getBody();
    console.log("answer:" + answer);
}, function(error) {
    var errorMessage = "Post Failed";
    if(error.code && error.body)
        errorMessage += " - " + error.code + ": " + error.body
    console.log(errorMessage);
    // dump the full object to see if you can formulate a better error message.
    console.log(error);
});
```